# Error: Did not check() all arguments during publisher

Tags: javascript, meteor, geolocation, iron-router

Im trying to display itemts within a distance (from user's location). Only the loading screen appears. Error message appears on the terminal (server).

**Publish**

```
  Meteor.publish('postsByDistance', function(currentLocation) { 
    return Posts.find({
      loc: { 
        $near: { 
        }...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check your arguments using `check();`. Take a look at the docs for [check()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check). In your case you should test against an Object (considering that the `Geolocation.latLng()` function from the MDG package returns an Object)

```
Meteor.publish('postsByDistance', function(currentLocation) { 
    check(currentLocation, Object);
    return Posts.find({
...
...
```

Also an option

```
check(currentLocation, Match.ObjectIncluding({lat: Number, lng: Number}))
```

Comment: Thanks! Whats the difference in the latter option?

Comment: I would use that to check for the individual keys of an Object (if I know them). In your case we know for sure that `currentLocation` will always have a `lat` and `lng` as unique keys. Any other form of Objects will be blocked. So first one is very general, second option is very specific to your example.